# Pandas not reading the Dot character

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
f = pd.read_csv(location,delimiter='\t\t',skiprows=2)

f['DFA'] = 'http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt'
```

On running the script,

I get the column as

```
http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
```

and not `http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt`

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import os,sys
from os import path
import re
import sys, ast
import subprocess
import numpy as np
#from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

location = "/root/madhu_test/bpstest/results/finalnss.txt"

with open (location, "r") as myfile:
         data=myfile.read().replace('\n', ' ')

print data
#print location
f = pd.read_csv(location,delimiter='\t\t',skiprows=2)
#f.apply(pd.Series.round)
#print f
cols = f.columns.tolist()
print cols
f = f.drop('BPS Profile.2', 1)
f = f.drop('BPS Profile.1', 1)
np.radians(f['Throughput'])
np.radians(f['Throughput.1'])
f.Throughput = f.Throughput.round()
f['Throughput.1'] = f['Throughput.1'].round()
f['percentage'] = ((f['Throughput.1']-f['Throughput'])/f['Throughput.1'])*100.0
f['percentage.1'] = ((f['Throughput.2']-f['Throughput'])/f['Throughput.2'])*100.0
f['Throughput.2'] = f['Throughput.2'].round()

f.percentage = f.percentage.round(1)
f['percentage.1'] = f['percentage.1'].round(1)

f['DFA'] = 'http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt'
print f
cols = f.columns.tolist()

#print cols
cols = ['BPS Profile', 'Throughput', 'DFA', 'Throughput.1', 'percentage', 'Throughput.2','percentage.1']
f = f[cols]
f.columns = ['BPS Profile', '2464 Throughput', '2464 DFA', '2482 Throughput', 'percentage', '2483 Throughput','Percentage']
f.to_html('/root/madhu_test/bpstest/results/outnss.html')
```

On running this I get this output:

```
['BPS Profile', 'Throughput', 'BPS Profile.1', 'Throughput.1', 'BPS Profile.2', 'Throughput.2']
           BPS Profile  Throughput  Throughput.1  Throughput.2  percentage  \
0    SigTestHTTP21kBin         217           219           453         0.9
1   SigTestHTTP21kHtml         359           364           372         1.4
2   SigTestHTTP21kText         380           376           378        -1.1
3     NSS-HTTP21Kdelay         378           380           378         0.5
4          NSS-HTTPCPS       18920            75            76    -25126.7
5    SIggTestPerimeter         270           223           232       -21.1
6    SIgTestDatacenter         371           373           361         0.5
7        NSS-Financial           5            56            57        91.1
8        NSS-Education         971          1010           958         3.9
9       NSS-EuroMobile         921           933           942         1.3
10        NSS-USMobile         528           542           633         2.6

    percentage.1                                                DFA
0           52.0  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
1            3.4  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
2           -0.6  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
3            0.0  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
4       -24821.0  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
5          -16.2  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
6           -2.7  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
7           91.2  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
8           -1.4  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
9            2.2  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
10          16.5  http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464...
```

Comment: that's just a display option. the full data is in there.

Comment: the default max_colwidth for display by default is 50 characters, hence you see `...`you can change this using `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth, 200) or some other large value, but the data is actually there

Comment: nope. it still shows as ...

Comment: Well you'll have to post raw input data and code to reproduce your error

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on pandas 0.16.0

Comment: added code in the qn

Comment: How does your error relate in anyway to your original question title and original question?

Comment: apologize, changed the code and subsequent output.

Comment: Try setting `display.width`, so `pd.set_option('display.width', 500)`, the default is 80 which could be the reason it's clipping the output